# Random Numbers and Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, random

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double main(){
  int N, x;

  printf("\nEnter the number of randoms to go into the array = ");
  scanf("%d", &N);

  double myArray[N];

  srand(time(NULL));

  for(x = 0; x < N; x++){
    myArray[x] = (rand() % 101);
    printf("myArray[x]: %d\n" , myArray[x]);
  }

  printf("\n Unsorted Array \n");
  for(x = 0; x < N; x++)
  printf("myArray[x]: %d\n" , myArray[x]);

  BubbleSort(myArray);

  printf("\n Sorted Array \n");
  for(x = 0; x < N; x++)
  printf("myArray[x]: %d\n" , myArray[x]);  
}
```

Here is my code. What I need to do is create random values from 0-100 and then sort those numbers. However, I can't seem to get the numbers to store in C properly. When I use a test of `5` my output is:

```
myArray[x]: -30926580
myArray[x]: -28464932
myArray[x]: -17742016
myArray[x]: -5561396
myArray[x]: -6919840
```

Unsorted Array

```
myArray[x]: 2048
myArray[x]: 2304
myArray[x]: 2560
myArray[x]: 2816
myArray[x]: 3072
```

Sorted Array

```
myArray[x]: 3584
myArray[x]: 3840
myArray[x]: 4096
myArray[x]: 4352
myArray[x]: 4608
```

I've read through several threads before and I can't seem to find out why my random isn't working.

Comment: `double main(){`: `main` returns `int`, not `double`.

Comment: You´re printing doubles with %d too. Use integers.

Comment: If you're doing all your work with integers, why have you created an array of double-precision floating point numbers (`double myArray[N]`)??

Comment: If you stepped through your code in a debugger, you would of course know that random is working just fine, and your array has correct values in it, and it would be ***obvious*** that you're just printing them wrong.  ***Moral of the story:*** Always use a debugger!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of `printf()`'s little nuances is that the `%d`substitution stands for "decimal," not "double." "Decimals" are integers, and passing doubles where `printf` expects integers will result in mangled output.

To print out a double, use the `%f` specifier, which stands for "float."

Additionally, the `main` function is supposed to return `int`, not `double`. Not a massive issue, but returning `double` is nonstandard and may confuse the executing environment.

Answer (score 1):

myArray is typed as array of doubles and you print it as ints.
If you want to print them, use %lf.